# Finding a specific field in firestore with an id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know this is a very basic question, but I am new to reactjs and firebase. After two days I am giving up on searching for an answer myself.

I have a firestore database 'MusicList' containing several documents. Within these documents the field 'seperatedStrings' holds (you'll probably will be guessing it) artists and titles of songs.
[image of the firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI0PQ.png)

**How do I retrive the value a single field** (in this example 'seperatedString') **using the ID** (in this example '5ajnHZ8YDaiYvTAvJ1ec'?

Whenever I am querying for this:

`firestore().doc("MusicList/" + "5ajnHZ8YDaiYvTAvJ1ec").seperatedString`

the console claims that it is "undefined" (That is a lie!), I'd expect 'Phil Upchurch Blackgold'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using Firebase queries correctly. If you want to fetch a document from a collection, you would do so like this:

```
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('MusicList')
    .doc('5ajnHZ8YDaiYvTAvJ1ec')
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
        if (doc && doc.exists) {
            const { separatedString } = doc.data();
            //use separatedString
        }
    });
```

Check out [Firestore - Get A Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) for more information.

Also, it would probably be better to structure your documents differently. You could have an `artist` and `track` field, and use `doc.data().artist` and `doc.data().track` respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply!

Unfortunatly, I still get the message that the field "undefined" when I replace
´//use separatedString` with `console.log(seperatedString);`. I double checked this with a few IDs.

Comment: @Danielo I just noticed that your field in firebase is mispelled. The variable I initialized is called `separatedString` with an "a", but the field in your document is `seperatedString` with an "e". Either change `const { separatedString } = doc.data();` in my example, or correct the spelling in your collection :)

Comment: Also consider splitting that into two fields, `artist` and `track` as I pointed out. You'll find it much easier to use your data in the future. The way you have it now, you'll have a difficult time splitting the artist and the song name.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a little embarrassing. It works fine now. Thanks you very much Michael! 

I would split the artist and track, but the initial data set is a mess, so I'll have no way of correcting it. 

Anyway, have a good day! It helped a lot.